# Import test sources from another project

Tags: unit-testing, netbeans-8

I have two Java Netbeans projects A and B, both projects contain unit tests.
The unit tests are implemented using TestNG, but I don't think that my problem is specific to TestNG, so it could also be JUnit.

In project A, I have implemented a helper class `MyHelper` in the test packages, to be used in the unit tests. It depends on class `AnotherClassFromA` from the source packages.

**Structure of the projects**

Project A

- Source Packages

  - ClassFromA.java
  - AnotherClassFromA.java
- Test Packages

  - ClassFromATest.java
  - MyHelper.java -> imports `AnotherClassFromA`

Now in project B, I also have unit tests. I would like to import the class `MyHelper` in the unit tests in order to reuse existing code.

Project B

- Source Packages

  - ClassFromB.java
- Test Packages

  - ClassFromBTest.java -> I would like to import `MyHelper` here

I have already added project A to project B's libraries, because other classes from A are required in B (in project B: Properties -> Libraries -> Compile tab -> Add Project).
But because `MyHelper` is implemented in project A's test packages (not in its source packages), it is not in the classpath of project B's test packages.

**I have already tried without success:**

1. To add project A to B's Compile Test Libraries (in project B: Properties -> Libraries -> Compile Tests tab -> Add Project), but `MyHelper` is not in the class path.
2. To add the path of A's test packages to B's test package folders (in project B: Properties -> Sources -> Test Package Folder -> Add Folder), but I get the error '*Package Folder already used in Project*'.
3. To create a third project C which adds project A as a library (in project C: Properties -> Libraries -> Compile tab -> Add Project) and implements `MyHelper` in project C's source packages (not test packages). Then I add C as a compile tests library to project A (in project A: Properties -> Libraries -> Compile Tests tab -> Add Project), but I get the error '*Can't add cyclic references*'.

One solution would be to split project A into several smaller projects, but as A is quite complex, I would rather prefer not to do that. So are there other approaches how I could achieve this?

I use Netbeans version is 8.2 and the projects are build using Ant.